# bigram calculation - Memory error, large file problem

Tags: python, nltk, n-gram

Here is a code for bigram calculation from the text corpus:

```
import sys
import csv
import string

import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.util import ngrams
from collections import Counter

tokenizer   = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')

with open('hugefile.csv', 'r') as file:
    
            text  = file.read()
                
            token = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
            trigrams = ngrams(token,3)
            count = Counter(trigrams)

            with open('out.csv','w') as csvfile:
                
                for tag, count in count.items():  
                
                    csvfile.write('{},{},{},{}\n'.format(tag[0], tag[1], tag[2], count))
```

**The error:**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSPanel\domains\vad\freq.py", line 17, in <module>
    text = file.read();
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen codecs>", line 322, in decode
MemoryError
```

The code works correct in cases where hugefile.csv is relativity small.
And problems begin when file is really huge (several GB), script stop working.

How to solve that problem?
Thanks.

**Updated:**

```
import sys
import csv
import string

import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.util import ngrams
from collections import deque
from collections import Counter

tokenizer   = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')

def ngram_iter(it, n=3):
    
    fifo = deque(maxlen=3)
    for line in it:
        for token in tokenizer.tokenize(line):
            fifo.append(token)
            if len(fifo) == n:
                yield list(fifo)
                
# Create an empty counter to store the trigram counts

with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    
            count = Counter(ngram_iter(file, 3))

            with open('out_2.csv','w') as csvfile:
                
                for tag, freq in count.items():  
                
                    csvfile.write('{},{},{},{}\n'.format(tag[0], tag[1], tag[2], freq))
```

**Error:**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "freq2.py", line 30, in <module>
    count = Counter(ngram_iter(file, 3))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\collections\__init__.py", line 599, in __init__
    self.update(iterable, **kwds)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\collections\__init__.py", line 690, in update
    _count_elements(self, iterable)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Does the whole file need to be in memory at the same time? Or can you just read chunks & overwrite storage?

Comment: Buy more RAM sticks :-)

Comment: Newlines are not word characters. You can read the file line-by-line and make your own n-grams

Comment: You seem to have omitted the actual error. Please [edit] to include the full traceback.

Comment: @tripleee - updated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I understand what n-grams are correctly, you can make the following iterator that technically avoids loading the entire file at once. You might still have an overly large `Counter` if there are insufficient repetitions among the n-grams, but that's a separate problem (which you can solve by writing the intermediate n-gram data to disk and sorting to emulate the behavior of a disk-based counter).

```
from collections import deque

def ngram_iter(it, n=3):
    """
    it: any iterator of strings, be it file, list, generator, or whatever
    """
    fifo = deque(maxlen=3)
    for line in it:
        for token in tokenizer.tokenize(line):
            fifo.append(token)
            if len(fifo) == n:
                yield ' '.join(fifo)
```

Now you can create the counter without loading the entire file at once:

```
Counter(ngram_iter(file, 3))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question updated with your block. Hoverer I have an error. Please take a look.

Comment: Try `yield(' '.join(fifo))`

Comment: @XTRUST.ORG. Fixed

Comment: @tripleee. Thanks for the catch. I didn't pay too much attention to the interface since I always expect OP to understand and adapt the idea. That's on me :)